# Set error message only on errornous field(s) when validating multiple instances of the same field

Tags: forms

- I have a form where the users can add one or more "units".
- I want to validate and return an error message on the problematic field when
  the unit does not have a value "leader"
- With the below code, an error message appears under *all* unit fields even if some
  inputs do not have error.

How can I add the error message only to the problematic field? Here's my attempt so far.

```php
    // Foreach $values['unit'], check if this field has the key
    // "leader". If not, add an error message and require the user
    // to select a sub field which has area leaders.
    if ($values['unit']) {
      foreach ($values['unit'] as $unit) {
        if (empty($unit["leader"])) {
          $form_state->setErrorByName('unit',
            new TranslatableMarkup('Please select a unit with a leader.'));
          break;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is this an a form validation handler or an element validation handler or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the code is a form validation handler, you should be able to do something like this:

```php
if ($values['unit']) {
  foreach ($values['unit'] as $index => $unit) {
    if (empty($unit['leader'])) {
      $form_state->setError($form['unit']['widget'][$index],t('Please select a unit with a leader.'));
    }
  }
}
```

However, if the `unit` element of the form is a child of a tree, then the first argument to `setError()` must be updated to the actual location of the element within the `$form` array.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me to `setError`! I notice that the $values array has an item "add more", which holds information for the "add more" button. After adding `array_pop($units);` to remove this "add more" array, your code works. Really appreciate your time!